# Data duplication on Data Save

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat

REST API coded in java Spring framework running in Tomcat. Facing data duplication problem on save as client calls save twice on some scenario. Knew it can be controlled by making changes in UI to stop resending but in our scenario that is not possible as need to traverse to next screen with Post-Save data in response.

So is there any mechanism to recheck server if correct data is saved even if connection is dropped before getting response.

Comment: How are you storing the data in the database ?

Comment: it is stored in Mysql in multiple table under single transaction. Read that when client connection is dropped a exception might raise , so  tried to Rollback on any exception, but even then duplicates happens

Comment: Easy solution would be to disable the save button till a response comes back. Difficult solution will be to check the database for duplicates before saving. If there is duplicate try and alert the user.